# Add values to context for render in Django

Tags: python, django

I have the following code inside a view:

```py
return render(
        request,
        'home/index.html',
        {
            'mobile':False,
            'title':'Home',
            #'year': datetime.now().year,
        }
    )
```

So I used to always calculate the year in every view. I had to since it was needed in my layout.html

Because of that I thought it would be a good idea to extract this calculation so I don't have to write it in each view specifically.
I tried this using the following middleware:

```py
from datetime import datetime
from django.utils.translation import gettext as _

def get_vars(get_response):
    def middleware(request):
        request.year = datetime.now().year
        return get_response(request)
    return middleware
```

But it seems that the year variable is not added the same way it would be in the view.

So my question is:

**How can I implement this functionality?**`

**If not with a middleware how can I otherwise do it?**

Comment: For displaying current year in template you can use [now tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#now). Just like this: ```{% now "Y" %}```. No need to pass this parameter in view.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably already importing the project's `settings.py` in your `views.py`, which is where I'll assume this code comes from. My solution when I ran against this issue was just to initialize the year in `settings.py`:

```
CURRENT_YEAR = datetime.now().year
```

and then, in `views.py`:

```
import my_app.settings as django_settings
...
return render(
    request,
    'home/index.html',
    {
        'mobile':False,
        'title':'Home',
        'year': django_settings.CURRENT_YEAR,
    }
)
```

Admittedly, my use case is different in that I was saving the most recent Monday, and checking occasionally that it hadn't changed and updating it automatically. If you set the year this way without changing it later within the program, then you'll have to actually restart the program for the changes to take effect.